# How to add strings from multiple columns to multiple rows in a single column in R

Tags: r, linux, string, bigdata

I have a data frame in R **(with more than 30 columns and 5000 rows)** that looks like this:

> Q 1 2 3 4 5
>   1 A A B C C
>   2 D E F
>   3 H I   C C
>   4 X Y Y Y Z
>   5 A E F C Z

I would like to:
1) remove duplicates in each column
2) move each string in each column into additional rows (e.g.: row 6, 7, 8 etc..) in the first column
3) remove duplicates in the first column

I've tried to look around, but they usually ask for strings to be added into 1 column and separated by ";" or "-", which is not what I'm looking for..

Any solutions? I'm also open to saving my data.frame into a .txt file and using linux/Mac Terminal to solve the problem.

Many thanks in advance!

[UPDATE:]
I thought the data should be reduced first, hence step 1. But agree to all that it can be done at step 3.

The final data.frame should look like this:
Q 1
1 A
2 D
3 H
4 X
5 E
6 I
7 B
8 F
9 C
10 Z
etc...

The strings are actually gene names which may be replicated within rows and columns. It is not ideal to format them in Excel due to changes in gene names. Hope this clears things up. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your expected output? I'm not clear on what you want to end up with.

Comment: Remember that your columns must all have the same length.

Comment: Agreed with @thelatemail; why do you remove dupes from column 1 twice (once during step 1, then again during step 3). What do you mean by removing dupes? Replace the duplicate entry with something else? Remove the row? Remove the column?

Comment: @DanHall: Yes, the columns all have more than 5000 rows. Missing strings in rows are listed as "NA" in R (or rather kept as blank).

Comment: I very nicely converted your table into an R object and added that to your question for you. Why did you remove it?

Comment: @DanHall: I'm sorry! I edited that question and it got removed. Sorry, I'm really a noob at this. Please do not get offended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text = "Q 1 2 3 4 5
1 A A B C C
2 D E F '' ''
3 H I C C ''
4 X Y Y Y Z
5 A E F C Z", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data.frame(x = unique(as.character(as.matrix(DF[2:length(DF)]))))
```

Row numbers are assigned automatically. Name your row whatever you want.

Comment: Resolved! I just had to change "length" in your code to "nrow". Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to have something like this?

```
final_df <- data.frame(V1 = unique(unlist(df[!is.na(df)])))
```

**Output is:**

```
   V1
1   A
2   D
3   H
4   X
5   E
6   I
7   Y
8   B
9   F
10  C
11  Z
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c("A", "D", "H", "X", "A"), X2 = c("A", "E", 
"I", "Y", "E"), X3 = c("B", "F", "C", "Y", "F"), X4 = c("C", 
NA, "C", "Y", "C"), X5 = c("C", NA, NA, "Z", "Z")), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Had this error instead.. "Error in `[.data.table`(test, !is.na(test)) : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657."

Comment: You should share input data using `dput(head(df))`